# Customize task resources on Airflow using MesosExecutor

Tags: mesos, airflow

Is it possible to specify resources (CPU, memory, GPU, disk space) for each operator of a DAG when using MesosExecutor?

I know you can specify global values for resources of a task.

For instance, I have several operators that are CPU expensive and others that not. I would like to execute one at a time of the first, but many in parallel of the non CPU expensive ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [code](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/executors/mesos_executor.py#L67) (mesos_executor.py line 67), it seems that is not possible since cpu and memory values are passed to the Scheduler during initialization:

```
    def __init__(self,
             task_queue,
             result_queue,
             task_cpu=1,
             task_mem=256):
    self.task_queue = task_queue
    self.result_queue = result_queue
    self.task_cpu = task_cpu
    self.task_mem = task_mem
```

and those [values are used](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/executors/mesos_executor.py#L153) without modification:

```
cpus = task.resources.add()
            cpus.name = "cpus"
            cpus.type = mesos_pb2.Value.SCALAR
            cpus.scalar.value = self.task_cpu

            mem = task.resources.add()
            mem.name = "mem"
            mem.type = mesos_pb2.Value.SCALAR
            mem.scalar.value = self.task_mem
```

**It requires a custom Executor implementation to achieve that**

Comment: Encountered the issue before and arrived at the same conclusion.